# How to fit uiimage from camera after cropping?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Hello everyone I am taking a photo from camera or photo library. I have a crop function that will crop the image to 1280 * 520 pxs. I have a uiimageview which width is 320 * 130 pxs. The problem I am facing is that its not fitting the uiimageview fully. I can see blank spaces on top and bottom.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTopLeft];
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

**Content Modes :** Look at [Documetation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentMode)

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```

Comment: I have resized the image
  CGSize size=CGSizeMake(320, 130);//set the width and height
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
Still i am having the blank spaces on top & bottom. I will try to set what u suggested, but wont it be deformed?. The idea behing the cropping is to have a perfect image with no deformation.

Comment: @veereef : Can you add the Screenshot ?

Comment: done please check :) the 2nd picture is your solution [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

Comment: @veereef : Try to use one of the content mode described in my Answer and Take a look at Documentation for further understanding.

Comment: see the 1st picture, although the uiimageview is 320 * 130 and the uiimage is 320 * 130 its not taking up the whole space..........

Comment: @veereef : Try to use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`..

Comment: hello there thanks for your answer infact it had to do with the autosizing .. .. which i had to set top & left only. Previously it was set for top left right bottom and flexible width & height.